# Git - Copy existing branch in one repository to non-existant branch in second repository

Tags: git

I am working between two separate repositories which are mostly synchronized. I somewhat understand the designations of different remote sources for the purposes of git pull and git push, and can synchronize any changes in existing branches utilizing these commands.

I run into problems when there is a new branch created in a repository. What is the recommended way to copy/clone/merge the new branch in repository A, when no such branch exists in repository B?. I have searched throughout many solutions, and I have yet to find a clean way of accomplishing this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Wouldn't `git push B <branch name>` from A or `git pull A <branch name>` from B accomplish what you want?

Comment: Generally the idea is to have one repository per project. Is there a specific reason you're trying to have identical code in different repositories? If you're looking to store your code in two different locations, you may want two *origins*, which can be done from a single repository.

Comment: I cannot have a single repository because it crosses company boundaries. Consequently, 2 repositories.

Comment: No. A Pull A  <branch name> form B results in a merge to whatever branch I have checked out from A. I get merge conflicts which I am trying to avoid. I just want the new branch from repo B copied to repo A, along with its history.

Comment: So more detail: I cloned repository B and then created repository A based on that clone. Push and pull commands on branches known to both repos work as expected. However, I do not know how to cleanly copy a new branch from one repo to the other.

Comment: "I run into problems when there is a new branch created in a repository" What problems do you run into, exactly?

Comment: The problem is that if there isn't a remote branch created in RepoB, then a pull of that branch from RepoA will result in a merge to whatever branch was last checked out out on RepoB. This is not the desired behavior.

The answer, as was provided below, is to first do a git remote add of the new branch name on RepoB, then fetch and checkout the new branch on RepoA, then push it to RepoB

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes provides a great explanation of how remotes work, which was the key to me understanding how to copy a new branch to a different repository.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to push any branch to the remote repository, whether the branch already exists there or even if the two repositories share a common history.

The following should do it:

1. `git fetch repoA` - Fetch all of the branches from remote repository A into the local copy.
2. `git checkout repoA/my_branch` - Switch to the branch in the local copy that you want to push into repository B.  Note that this will not create a local branch, but the commit of repoA/my_branch will be checked out.
3. `git push repoB my_branch` - Push the current commit from the local copy into the new remote repository B branch.

If the branch name does not already exist in repository B then this should work just fine.

Note that this assumes that you have already added both remotes to your local repository using `remote add`.

Comment: This fixes my issue. The reason it was not working for me earlier is I did not do the remote add to repoB. Thanks.